# Override the value of a static variable while using decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, decorator, python-decorators

I've created a class like the following:

```
class Simon:

    name = 'Simon'

    @classmethod
    def says(cls, sentence):
        return '%s says: %s' % (cls.name, sentence)
```

If I want *Simon* say *sit down*, I can do this:

```
>>> Simon.says('sit down')
'Simon says: sit down'
```

To substitute *Simon* with another name, say, *Eva*, I can subclass it like this:

```
class Eva(Simon):

    name = 'Eva'
```

And the result:

```
>>> Eva.says('stand up')
'Eva says: stand up'
```

Now I want to change *says* to *said* by creating a decorator called `to_past_tense`:

```
class Eva(Simon):

    name = 'Eva'

    def to_past_tense(self, func):
        def wrapper(*arg, **kw):
            present_tense = func(*arg, **kw)
            past_tense = present_tense.replace('says', 'said')
            return past_tense
        return wrapper

    @classmethod
    def says(cls, *arg, **kw):
        return cls.to_past_tense(cls, Simon.says)(*arg, **kw)
```

If I do this:

```
>>> Eva.says('stand up')
```

what I'm expecting is this:

```
'Eva said: stand up'
```

but in fact I got this

```
'Simon said: stand up'
```

How can I override the value?

And, please, help me improve the title if it isn't precise and clear, thank you!

Comment: See that hard-coded class name you have there: `return cls.to_past_tense(cls, Simon.says)(*arg, **kw)`

Comment: I've tried what @Daniel Roseman suggested, but with no vein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Simon.says`, retrieving a bound class.

If you wanted to get the overridden class method but have it bind to the current class, use a [`super()` proxy object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super):

```
@classmethod
def says(cls, *arg, **kw):
    return cls.to_past_tense(cls, super().says)(*arg, **kw)
```

The `super()` object will search the MRO of the class, find the `says` method on `Simon`, then bind it to the `cls` object for you, so the `cls.name` value is still looked up from `Eva`:

```
>>> class Simon:
...     name = 'Simon'
...     @classmethod
...     def says(cls, sentence):
...         return '%s says: %s' % (cls.name, sentence)
... 
>>> class Eva(Simon):
...     name = 'Eva'
...     def to_past_tense(self, func):
...         def wrapper(*arg, **kw):
...             present_tense = func(*arg, **kw)
...             past_tense = present_tense.replace('says', 'said')
...             return past_tense
...         return wrapper
...     @classmethod
...     def says(cls, *arg, **kw):
...         return cls.to_past_tense(cls, super().says)(*arg, **kw)
... 
>>> Eva.says('Hello')
'Eva said: Hello'
```

Comment: @OwenL: the current class in which you define this method should be, yes, as that is what `super()` then uses to find the next class in the MRO. In Python 3, you can use `super().says`, so no arguments.

Comment: @OwenL: ah, you tagged this as Python 3. Will update.

Comment: Perfect! Thank a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here, but I suppose you need to pass `cls.says` to the method:

```
return cls.to_past_tense(cls, cls.says)(*arg, **kw)
```

Comment: but I got this: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: That's because `cls.say` points to `Eva.say`, so yes, this causes the method to call itself.